# Embedding vbs file to image

Tags: vbscript, imagemagick

how to embed vbs file to image and run the vbs file when an image is clicked  or open by the users? Please provide me with a good solution

Comment: Isnt it simpler to run a script when the image is clicked on? rather than trying to embed the vbs into an image? Also embeding a vbs file into an image sounds very suspect too!

Comment: @ZafKhan yeah it is simpler and I can do that but isn't it interesting when someone click the image and some kind of script run on background  on the system. I know it can harm the system if script is dangerous but i wanna know if it is possible or not and how but only for educational purpose as me myself is an IT student doing BIT. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess it's possible, but as far as i know there is no commercial software that lets you embed script into images (for very good reason too). You would have to convert your vb script into the character/color code values and add it to your photo. this would give you three chracters per pixel working on the basis of RGB(rr,gg,bb) where each rr and gg and bb can be 0-255 (think of it as 3 characters of ascii value) You would also have to CLIP your image so as not to show the embedded script which would be visible otherwise as gobble-de-gook (various pixels colors values based on the script).

Comment: @ZafKhan but is there any software to convert script into color code or hex code.Seems so hard to encode script to the color code then  to images again :( have you tried doing it and succeed and let me know if can provide me with real implemantation.

Answer (score 0):

Running arbitrary code in the background when a user opens an image file would be a severe vulnerability. So no, there is no regular way to achieve what you want.

Comment: so assuming it is true, why it is said to not open any file that you see in social media. they say even image files could have viruses in them. Why they are warning us?? I heard this from tv.